# Access Flask Application URL always return 404

Tags: flask

I have written a quite simple flask web application, 
the git repository is: https://github.com/jualy007/navigation

My problem is that I can find Rule Map:

```
Rule '/home' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> home.hometest
```

But when access `URL 127.0.0.1:8000/home`, always failed with `404`, debug logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019 18:25:35] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I have no idea, can anyone help find the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is SERVER_NAME configuration in config, after delete SERVER_NAME, all is fine.